# Symfony: Only Change Displayed Relations of a EntityType Field

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm having a many-to-many relationship between the tables `User` and `Group`. Some of the groups are assigned to the users automatically based on their type. Other groups can be managed by the administrators using the user edit form.

In order to achieve that the administrators can only manage the groups that the are supposed to, I'm using the `query_builder` option of the `EntityType` form type.

```
$builde->add('groups', EntityType::class, [
    // ...
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('g')
                  ->where('g.type = ?1')
                  ->setParameter(1, 'user_managed');
    },
    'multiple' => true,
    // ...
]);
```

My problem is now that up on saving the user entity only the groups that were selected in the form are associated to the user and that all associations that were not displayed are deleted.

Is there a way to only change the association of the displayed groups to the user instead of all of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mapped option in your type in order to not directly map the information in the object :

```
$builder->add('groups', EntityType::class, [
    // ...
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('g')
                  ->where('g.type = ?1')
                  ->setParameter(1, 'user_managed');
    },
    'multiple' => true,
    // ...
    'mapped' => false
]);
```

Like that the information doesn't override the group attribute in your object. 
After the form validation you get the submitted information :

```
$groups = $form->get("group")->getData();
```

And now you can check the difference between the two arrays $user->groups and $groups.

Comment: It's quite a big deal that way but it works perfectly fine. Thanks!